# fwrite(): send of 21 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Tags: magento2.3, message-queue, rabbit-mq

I am using custom RabbitMQ message queues in custom Magento 2 extension.

When i run consumer using the following command:

```
sudo php bin/magento  queue:consumers:start custom.json.update
```

Consumer works for 2 to 3 seconds and gives the following error:

> "fwrite(): send of 21 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe".

I found same issue reported in github but no solution there either.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25947

My Magento version is 2.3.2.

Please anyone know how to resolve this issue?